# How does traveling to a wing member work?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I want to join in a wing with a player in solo/private session.  he will be in the default starting point, and I am quite a way from that.  I believe that i will be teleported to him using the wing beacon, but I'm unsure of something.  I'm quite far away from the starting point, and I don't want to have to travel all that way again, will the game teleport me back to where i was when I leave the wing?  how does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you join or leave a wing, your position in the galaxy does not change. If you wish to group up with your friend, you will need to travel to them. Wing beacons only work within a single system, with a navlock range on the order of a few hundred Ls. You will not be transported across the galaxy and back when joining a wing.

Additionally, if your friend is *in* the starter zone, you will need a starter zone permit, which if you have any rank above harmless, penniless, and aimless, you won't have. Of course if they're merely *around* the starter zone you won't need a permit.